# auto close or auto migrate questions with subject like "can't boot"

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It seems to me there are [more and more questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=boot%20closed%3Ayes) of users asking why their computer won't boot up.

Can't we have a system that auto flag/close /migrate those type of question ? Maybe some keywords can raise a red flag ? (won't boot / start etc...)

Comment: Boot-loaders are a thing that people program. Having their software run on boot up is a thing. Questions like ["Rails boots but won't serve pages"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rails+boots) are completely on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

That query reveals 618 questions. Out of ~8,000 questions posted *every day*!

If we search for "[boot closed:no](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=boot+closed%3Ano)", we get a whopping 15,010 results, many of which seem to be useful and on-topic.

So that means only about 4% of the questions are bad enough to be closed. Not a bad ratio! I suspect there are *many* tags with worse ratios.

Comment: Well, their *not* being closed doesn't necessarily mean they shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @James True, of course, but even if a grand half of those questions 'should' be closed, that still leaves us with almost 8,000 valid on-topic questions.